# filemaker 15 Pro server preformance

Tags: filemaker

I creating a database in Filemaker, the database is about 1GB and includes around 500 photos.

Filemaker maker server is having performance issues, its crashes and takes it’s time when searching though the database. My IT department recommended to raise the cache memory.

I raised the memory 252MB but it's still struggling to give a consistent performance. The database shows now peaks in the CPU.

What can cause this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Verify at FileMaker.com that your server meets the minimum requirements  for your version. 
For starters:
Increase the cache to 50% of the total memory available to FileMaker server. 
Verify that the hard disk is unfragmented and has plenty of free space.

Answer (score 0):

FM Server should be extremely stable.

FMS only does two things:

- reads data from the disk and sends it to the network
- takes data from the network and writes it to the disk

Performance bottlenecks are always disk and network. FMS is relatively easy on CPU and RAM unless Web Direct is being used.

Things to check:

- Are users connecting through ethernet or wifi? (Wifi is slow and unreliable.)
- Is FMS running in a virtual machine?
- Is the machine running a supported operating system?
- Is the database using Web Direct? (Use a 2-machine deployment for web direct.)
- Is there anything else running on the machine? (Disable virus and indexing.)
- Make sure users are accessing the live databases through FMP client and not through file sharing.
- How are the database being backed up? NEVER let anything other than FMS see the live files. Only let OS-level backup processes see backup copies, never the live files.
- Make sure all the energy saving options on the server are DISABLED. You do NOT want the CPU or disks sleeping or powering down.
- Put the server onto an uninterruptible power supply (UPS). Bad power could be causing problems.